# How to log a chat conversation with Bot Framework C# Bot Builder

Tags: logging, bots, botframework

I would like to log my bot conversations (to a text file or DB).  I want to capture all of the input and output from the bot, including any text generated by FormFlow, Confirms, etc.  I don't need the graphical elements like cards, but it would be nice to have the text from them too.

It doesn't seem practical to add logging statements after each input/output in my app, particularly since I can't easily tell exactly what text was sent to the user by FormFlow.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What you think about getting all text with time in one txt file and then you can store it in DB

Answer (score 12):

You can log all messages (from bot or from user) using [Middleware](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/whats-new/#middleware).

For C# version you must implement the [IActivityLogger](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/d77/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_history_1_1_i_activity_logger.html) and log what you want in the LogAsync method.

For Example:

```
public class DebugActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"From:{activity.From.Id} - To:{activity.Recipient.Id} - Message:{activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}");
    }
}
```

Finally, you must register in AutoFact with something like this (in global.asax):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<DebugActivityLogger>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();
builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

If you're using the nodejs version, its more straightforward:

```
const logUserConversation = (event) => { console.log('message: ' + event.text + ', user: ' + event.address.user.name);
};
// Middleware for logging
bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please add code for bot framework V4, with dotnet core..
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.  I can use the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.History.IActivityLogger Interface

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dc/dc6/namespace_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_history.html

Comment: How do you use it?

Comment: @Tas D The link that you posted , just take you to the generic bot documentation page only