# Access Microsoft Bot Framework conversation history / logs

Tags: bots, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

For the purpose of retraining and improving my bot, am I able to somewhere download / access the logs of all conversations that users had with my LUIS-enabled bot? I am not able to find anything like this in the Microsoft Bot Framework portal.
I am also trying to better understand how LUIS identifies suggested utterances. Some conversations that users had with my bot doesn't appear to hit the correct intent, so I want to retrain with historical user data, but there doesn't appear to be any logs available.

The only related information I can find suggests that I need to manually implement the functionality to log a conversation through IActivityLogger, as captured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309532/how-to-log-a-chat-conversation-with-bot-framework-c-sharp-bot-builder).
I am not really after full logs of the conversations, but rather the ability to use historical conversations for improved training of my LUIS app.

Thanks,

Pieter van Aarde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download all the queries that hit my LUIS endpoint on the My apps page in the LUIS portal, as highlighted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO0UB.png). Still have some questions around using this for training, but will raise in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The Bot Framework does not store any conversation history; primarily for privacy reasons. You already have described a good path to keep a log of your own.

LUIS will suggest utterances to you that it thinks may improve your model if you review the utterances in your Intents. LUIS will only suggest those it thinks will have an impact to your model - not all utterances.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Bot Framework uses the Bot Framework State to store conversation data. It is designed for prototyping, and is useful for development and testing environments. At the time of this writing, it has only a size limit of 32KB. Learn more about data management.

For production environments, it’s highly recommended to use a NoSQL database to store data as documents, such as Azure Cosmos DB. It's a multi-model database (like document, graph, key-value, table and column-family models) that can offer some key benefits.

Check here: [bot-conversation-history-with-azure-cosmos-db](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/bot-conversation-history-with-azure-cosmos-db/)