# Unable to log messages using IActivityLogger and the Bot Builder for C#

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, botframework

I need to log the messages between my users and my bot. After some research I found this post by sGambolati explaining how this can be achieved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42145416.

However this approach doesn't seems to be working for me. I even tried the same snippets he provided and I still don't see the log in the debug output window.

Here's the code according to his implementation:

The logger class:

```
public class DebugActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"From:{activity.From.Id} - To:{activity.Recipient.Id} - Message:{activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}");
    }
}
```

My Global.asax:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<DebugActivityLogger>()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerDependency();
        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
    }
}
```

The standard echo sample in the controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IActivityLogger` implementation will log incoming/outcoming messages going through an `IPostToBot`/`IBotToUser`  implementation. In this case, the [LogPostToBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/IActivityLogger.cs#L96) and the [LogPostToUser](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ConnectorEx/IActivityLogger.cs#L113) implementations are the responsible of calling the `IActivityLogger` implementation.

All this introduction, is just to let you know that if you use the `connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync` you won't be hitting the `IActivityLogger`. To hit the logger, you will need a `IDialog` that received the message from the user and you need to use `context.PostAsync` to log the messages from the bot to the user.

Take a look to the [core-Middleware](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-Middleware) C# sample to see this working.