# Bot Framework logging chat history (With ReplyToActivityAsync - isTyping indicator)

Tags: c#, botframework

how do I properly save chat conversation of user to bot? Yes, I have seen examples regarding about this, but it didn't worked. I also did not use `builder.Update()` because it is already obsolete. However, it seems like I have gotten it to work with from bot to user (same implementation). The problem is, right after I log the chat from user to bot, the bot stops responding (totally no response), it bugs me out because if I log from bot to user the code is still working continuously.

Here's the code:
**User to bot**

```
 public class UserToBotLoggerService : IPostToBot
{
    private readonly IConnectorClient _client;
    private readonly IMessageActivity _FromUser;
    public UserToBotLoggerService(IMessageActivity fromUser, IConnectorClient client)
    {
        SetField.NotNull(out _FromUser, nameof(fromUser), fromUser);
        SetField.NotNull(out _client, nameof(client), client);
    }
    public async Task PostAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var conversation = "";
        var convActivity = "";
        conversation = $"From: {activity.From.Name} \n\n To: {activity.Recipient.Name} \n\n Message: {activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}";
        convActivity = convActivity + conversation;

        await _client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync((Activity)activity, token);
    }
}
```

**MessageController**

```
public MessagesController()
    {
        //var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterType<UserToBotLoggerService>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();    
            });


    }
```

Here's the other implementation I used using `IActivityLogger`

```
        public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        var conversation = "";
        var convActivity = "";
        conversation = $"From: {activity.From.Name} \n\n To: {activity.Recipient.Name} \n\n Message: {activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}";
        convActivity = convActivity + conversation;

    }


 Conversation.UpdateContainer(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterType<BotToUserLoggerService>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            }
```

Thanks! PS: I still cannot insert a comment in a user thread due to in need of reputation of at least 50. So pardon me if there are duplicates regarding my question, in which I might I already have seen and tried their solution.

**Edit1:** I have found my bug, it seems like my isTyping activity indicator is the one blocking the `IActivityLogger` as it uses `ReplyToActivityAsync` as per [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347912/unable-to-log-messages-using-iactivitylogger-and-the-bot-builder-for-c-sharp)! So my problem is now the isTyping activity indicator.

**Edit2:** Also fixed my isTyping activity indicator.

I'll update my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to log messages using IActivityLogger and the Bot Builder for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347912/unable-to-log-messages-using-iactivitylogger-and-the-bot-builder-for-c-sharp)

Comment: @EzequielJadib Done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inherited `IActivityLogger`and implemented its function so I ended up with this

```
        public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
        {
            var conversation = "";
            var convActivity = "";
            conversation = $"From: {activity.From.Name} \n\n To: {activity.Recipient.Name} \n\n Message: {activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}";
            convActivity = convActivity + conversation;
        }
```

Yes, it is quite the same with the other issues on how to log the chat history, however, I discovered that my problem was on my `connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(message);` **this doesn't allow to hit the `IActivityLogger`, the `ReplyToActivityAsync`** so what I did, this might help anyone in the near future.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply();
            isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
            HandleSystemMessage(isTypingReply); //I passed the activity type to the HandleSystemMessage and let it handle the typingActivity;
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new YourDialog());
        }  
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

**HandleSystemMessage**

```
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
            connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(message);
        }
```

The `HandleSystemMessage` is the one handling the `ReplyToActivityAsync` wherein I miraculously discovered that it bypasses the `IActivityLogger` limitation, wherein it's like it has it's own world.